# Running AngularJS app in IE 9

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to run my angular app on IE 9 and stuck with a very weird problem.

My local machine has IE 9.0.36 and it works absolutely fine.

Our dev machine has IE 9.0.37 and it doesn't work at all (doesnt show any of the dropdowns, textboxes, buttons). I get the following error.

```
 [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!
```

Why dont I see this error in Chrome or IE 9.0.36? I have tried modifying the meta tag to the following but none works.

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9">

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">

 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">
```

Please suggest any thoughts?

Thank you[image]

Comment: How can I see errors in IE? I only know how to view errors in Chrome.

Comment: Have you a link to the live application? Also, check the console for any errors.

Comment: To get errors you can use F12 (Dev Tools in IE) and then view the Console tab

Comment: (which is the same key you can use in Chrome.)

Comment: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.bootstrap due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.bootstrap' is not available!    Why dont I see this error in Chrome or IE 9.0.36?

Comment: @bluepiranha Can you edit your question and put this comment in? The more information in the question itself, the better.

Comment: The error message indicates that the ui.bootstrap module is missing - the file path may be wrong on the dev server ?

Comment: @sirrocco I am using the same code in both the environment.

Comment: can you duplicate the behavior in a plunkr ?

Comment: @sirrocco Plunkr doesnt allow behavior on different browsers. Please see the screenshot

Comment: What do you mean? Just create a simple page that depends on ui.bootsttrap and try it in the 2 different browsers... If you can't duplicate the behavior then it's something with your setup.